# What's the better way to implement a condition at NHibernate query?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I am using a generics implementation of Query from NHibernate.
My method:

> ```
> public IEnumerable<TEntidade> ObterEntidadesPor(Func<TEntidade, bool> where)
>         {
>             return SessionNH.Query<TEntidade>().Where(where);
>         }
> ```

In this case, the NHibernate first do the **"select * from TEntidade"** bring all information to memory after all this, he implement the **"where"** conditional. This are taking to much time.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: why not use Entity Framework, (not sure about `NHibernate`) but EF translates `where` to `WHERE` clause in `SQL` and doesn't pull all records in memory to do filtering.

Comment: All applications here are using NHibernate. I can't change to EF without a big impact.

Comment: Try with `Expression<Func<TEntidade, bool>> where` instead

Comment: That's it! The `Expression<Func<TEntidade, bool>> where` work it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with `Expression<func>`.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntidade> ObterEntidadesPor(Expression<Func<TEntidade, bool>> where)
{
    return SessionNH.Query<TEntidade>().Where(where);
}
```

While searching for answer, a colleague told me that the `Func` executes the query before build an expression. To build an expression before executing the query, we have to use `Expression`.

This is also mentioned by @RomanArtiukhin in comments on question.